# Multiple validation schemes with attributes

Tags: c#, validation

I am using data annotations in C# to validate a POCO class.  I would like to be able to specify different validation schemes in different situations.  E.g. minimum validation for trusted data sources, but a higher level of validation for data collected via a website form open to the public.

I've Googled and i'm not sure if: A) I'm not using the right terms, or B) this is the wrong approach entirely which is why i'm not finding anything.  It seems like this might be a common need.

To illustrate what i'd like to do:

```
public class TestClass { 

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [WhitelistCharactersOnly(ValidationScheme = ValidationSchemes.Untrusted)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

}
```

I understand that I could do something with custom attributes but i'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel if possible.

So as not to solicit too much debate, my question is this: Is there a way to achieve what I want to do that is part of the C# framework at present?

Comment: I think you're looking for Attributes.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, I've used the word "annotations" in my question when I should have said "attributes".  Thanks, I am aware of attributes.

I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the MVC framework for validation you can take advantage of the `MetadataTypeAttribute`.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ICustomerValidation1))]
public class CustomerValidation1 : CustomerBase { }

public class CustomerBase
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
}


public interface ICustomerValidation1
{
  // Apply RequiredAttribute
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required.")]
  string Title { get; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, that looks to separate out the logic nicely too.  I will play around with this, if it works and no other suggestions are proffered i'll accept your answer tomorrow.

Comment: If not, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great (the pattern anyway as sadly i'm not using MVC so the validation ignores the associated interface by default).  
For the benefit of others: I got around the non MVC issue by implementing IValidatableObject in the base class for my entities, this allowed me to override the Validate method and manually validate against the property attributes defined in the associated interface specified by the MetadataType attribute.  Perhaps there is a better method, but this worked for me.